# cxf runtime exception unknown client side exception

Tags: java, mule

I am using a simple mule flow which takes a spring bean as a component and executes it periodically using quartz endpoint. My cxf client and configuration all look fine to me but for some reason i get an exception when trying to send request.

my class is as follows:

```
@Component
@DependsOn("restfulClient")
public class Transmitter implements Callable{

    private static final Logger logger = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(Transmitter.class);

    @Autowired
    private RestfulClient restfulClient; 

    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        logger.info("In Transmitter"); 
        try {
            String result = restfulClient.ping(); 
            logger.info("Result: {}" , result); 

        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("Exception in Transmitter" ,e); 
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

my client:

```
@Produces({"text/plain"})
@Path("/subscription")
public interface RestfulClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    public String ping(); 
}
```

in `applicationContext.xml` i have defined the cxf bean and enabled cxf logging:

```
<jaxrs:client id="restfulClient"
                serviceClass="com.ws.RestfulClient"
                address="${prop.restful.url}">
    <jaxrs:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </jaxrs:features>
</jaxrs:client>
```

and the url is defined in `application.properties` file and when in debugging mode it constructs the url successfully.

When i try the url on postman it works fine and i get `OK` as result but it is not working in the code.

the exception i get is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown client side exception
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.setResponseBuilder(AbstractClient.java:331)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleResponse(ClientProxyImpl.java:451)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:445)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:177)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.ping(Unknown Source)
at com.processor.Transmitter.onCall(Transmitter.java:77)
at org.mule.model.resolvers.CallableEntryPointResolver.invoke(CallableEntryPointResolver.java:46)
at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:36)
at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339)
at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82)
at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:73)
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:122)
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:57)
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:238)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:50)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:22)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:66)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:61)
at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:156)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:94)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:67)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:102)
at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:51)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:118)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:189)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:182)
at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:109)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:181)
at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:39)
at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Hi, could you share your complete mule flow xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is in

```
<jaxrs:features>
    <cxf:logging/>
</jaxrs:features>
```

which belonged for malformed schema...  (honestly am wondering why wouldn't mule give a name to such an error instead of vague unknown client side exception!)

```
<mule xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf 
<!-- -->
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd" >
```

the last link gives not found..